# PHPでRubyのようなキーワード引数はできますでしょうか？

Tags: php, ruby, 可読性

Rubyでは引数の順序を気にしないで、
下記のように書くことができます。
これをキーワード引数というそうです。

```
def self.piyo(msg: 'hello', name: 'Yamada')
  p "#{msg}, #{name}"
end
```

```
Hoge.piyo #=>"hello, Yamada"
Hoge.piyo(msg: 'Hi', name: 'Sato') #=> "Hi, Sato"
Hoge.piyo( name: 'Sato', msg: 'Hi') #=> "Hi, Sato"
```

そこで質問なのですが、PHPではこの機能はありますでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

コードは↓を参考にしています。
http://qiita.com/rtoya/items/33617078501776fdcad7

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: これが最新の状況なのかどうかわかりませんが、このリンク先の時点(2013-09-06 Update 22-05-2014 ?)[named_params](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) では、キーワード引数を実装するか考慮中という感じなので、「まだない」と思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPでは、[キーワード引数を言語に加えるという提案](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params)がありますが、キーワード引数は今のまま[不可能](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800379/named-arguments-in-php)です。

しかし、配列を使えます。例えば：

```
function piyo($args) {
  // 初期値を足す
  $args += array(
    'msg' => 'hello',
    'name' => 'Yamada'
  );

  echo("$args[msg], $args[name]");
}

piyo(array('msg' => 'Hi', 'name' => 'Sato')); // => "Hi, Sato"
piyo(array('name' => 'Sato', 'msg' => 'Hi')); // => "Hi, Sato"
```

PHP5.4では、`piyo(['msg' => 'Hi', 'name' => 'Sato']);`というシンタックスも使えます。

---

補足：JavaScriptのFunction.applyのように、[`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.call-user-func-array.php)も使えるようです。例えば：

```
function piyo($msg = 'hello', $name = 'Yamada') {
  echo("$msg, $name");
}

// => "Hi, Sato"
call_user_func_array(
  'piyo', array('msg' => 'Hi', 'name' => 'Sato')
); 
// => "Hi, Sato"
call_user_func_array(
  'piyo', array('name' => 'Sato', 'msg' => 'Hi')
);
```

この[SOの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282838)のように、[`extract`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.extract.php)も使えるようです：

```
function piyo($args = array(), $msg = 'hello', $name = 'Yamada') {
  extract($args);
  echo("$msg, $name");
}

piyo(array('msg' => 'Hi', 'name' => 'Sato')); // => "Hi, Sato"
piyo(array('name' => 'Sato', 'msg' => 'Hi')); // => "Hi, Sato"
```

Answer (score 3):

今のところ配列かオブジェクトで擬似的に表現するしかないかもですね。

```
function piyo($k) {
    echo $k['msg'] . ", " . $k['name'];
}
piyo(['msg' => 'hello', 'name' => 'Yamada']);
```